# how do I store and receive multiple values with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store multiple values and then retrieve them with `localStorage`. I would like a random number generated for each div with the class id and then store the random number. However, at the moment the same value is showing for each div but I want each class to generate a random number and save that number.

html

```
<div class="id"></div>
<div class="id"></div>
<div class="id"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.id').each(function() {

var min = 5,
        max = 20,
    random = min + Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

var count;
  if(localStorage.getItem("ct")){
    count = localStorage.getItem("ct");
  } else {
    count = random;
  }

$(this).html(count);
localStorage.setItem("ct", count);

});
```

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` on an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the index to the item name so each div has a unique one.

```
$('.id').each(function(index) {
var min = 5,
        max = 20,
    random = min + Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

var count;
  if(localStorage.getItem("ct"+index)){
    count = localStorage.getItem("ct"+index);
  } else {
    count = random;
  }

$(this).html(count);
localStorage.setItem("ct"+index, count);

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rm6xhv1j/

Answer (score 1):

One option is use an array and stringify it, this degrades in performance as it gets large because you have to parse the whole array to modify it and then stringify it again to store it back.

Another option is to use a number appended to the key so each item you wish to store has it's own spot in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("item_" + number, valueToStore);
```